# можно ли как то динамически менять параметры конфига nginx?

Tags: веб-программирование, nginx, lua, config

Есть возможность в конфиге `nginx` писать код на `lua`. Как я понимаю этот код исполняется при каждом запросе. Могу ли я хранить некоторые параметры конфига в базе, и с помощью `lua` их доставать?

Comment: Разве перезагрузка сервера `nginx` не потребуется?

Comment: Какую задачу вы хотите решить?

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д.